# WebGL Not Working in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I have a new Microsoft Surface 4 and I'm struggling to get WebGL to work in Chrome. It works fine in Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer, but Chrome simply fails.

If I go to http://get.webgl.org, I get this message in Edge:

> Your browser supports WebGL
>
> However, it indicates that support is experimental; Not all WebGL functionality may be supported, and content may not run as expected.

I also see the little spinning cube to show that WebGL is working.

If I go to that same page in Chrome, I get this:

> Hmm. While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable. If possible, please ensure that you are running the latest drivers for your video card

I've scoured the web trying to find out why this would not work in Chrome but I've not had any luck. If I go to chrome://gpu, this is what I see:

```
Graphics Feature Status

Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Flash: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Hardware accelerated
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Native GpuMemoryBuffers: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Video Encode: Hardware accelerated
WebGL: Hardware accelerated

Driver Bug Workarounds

clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
disable_discard_framebuffer
exit_on_context_lost
force_cube_complete
msaa_is_slow
scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args
texsubimage_faster_than_teximage

Problems Detected

Some drivers are unable to reset the D3D device in the GPU process sandbox
Applied Workarounds: exit_on_context_lost
TexSubImage is faster for full uploads on ANGLE
Applied Workarounds: texsubimage_faster_than_teximage
Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764, 349137
Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
Always rewrite vec/mat constructors to be consistent: 398694
Applied Workarounds: scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args
ANGLE crash on glReadPixels from incomplete cube map texture: 518889
Applied Workarounds: force_cube_complete
On Intel GPUs MSAA performance is not acceptable for GPU rasterization: 527565
Applied Workarounds: msaa_is_slow
Framebuffer discarding can hurt performance on non-tilers: 570897
Applied Workarounds: disable_discard_framebuffer
Accelerated rasterization has been disabled, either via about:flags or command line.
Disabled Features: rasterization
Native GpuMemoryBuffers have been disabled, either via about:flags or command line.
Disabled Features: native_gpu_memory_buffers

Version Information

Data exported   6/29/2016, 1:49:01 PM
Chrome version  Chrome/51.0.2704.106
Operating system    Windows NT 10.0
Software rendering list version 10.18
Driver bug list version 8.66
ANGLE commit id 1a1b30c37e13
2D graphics backend Skia
Command Line Args   --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
```

Any time I find guides that explain the various flags that need to be set in Chrome to enable WebGL, I find that I already have them all set appropriately.

For reference, here are my versions:

- Edge: 25.10586.0.0
- IE: 11.306.10586.0
- Chrome: 51.0.2704.106 m

My video card is Intel Iris Graphics 540 with up-to-date driver (v20.19.15.4409).

Any bright ideas from the community?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by fails? what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I posted the message I get some get.webgl.org (...your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable...). Nothing that uses WebGL loads in the browser. There's no specific error - the browser simply doesn't load those components. For example, on get.webgl.org, I can see the page fine, but the spinning cube does not appear. On chromeexperiments.com/webgl, I get a message saying "I'm sorry, no fallback for browsers with no working WebGL". That's not really an error from the browser, but a nice check from the developer to let me know why it didn't load.

Comment: try running chrome like this chrome.exe --disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds

Comment: No difference that I can detect. I get the exact same message from get.webgl.org.

Comment: how do you know it's not working without opening any webgl page on it?

Comment: get.webgl.org does include a WebGL element - it should display a spinning cube. When I access that page in IE, I see that spinning cube. When I access it in Chrome, I do not see that cube. Similarly, I've been trying different WebGL elements on chromeexperiments.com/webgl. I'm not sure what you mean because I've been *continually* trying to view pages with WebGL on them.